# Visual Studio Code: Reload VS Code to activate extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am looking for a way to reload VS Code to activate extensions through code.  Ideally, I would like to do this using the VS Code API but I haven't been able to find any information.  There a *Reload* command available through the command palette which gives the desired result.  Does anyone know of a way to reload through Typescript or Javascript?  I've also tried to use the command line as an option but it appears I need to load a new window to activate the extension which still leaves the active window open.  I've added a screenshot for context.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I may have found a way to do this using workbench.action.reloadWindow.  Will test out to confirm.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically reload Visual Studio Code window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126031/how-to-programmatically-reload-visual-studio-code-window)

Answer (score -1):

I meant to resolve this awhile back, thanks for the reminder.  I used a combination of workbench.action.closeWindow and workbench.action.newWindow to achieve the desired result.