# How to programmatically reload Visual Studio Code window?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

User can achieve this by running 'Reload Window' available via editor's 'Command Palette'. That however from an extension authoring point of view is not as straight forward as prompting the user right away.

Desired outcome is to take current implementation in [this](https://github.com/xabikos/vscode-javascript/pull/35) pull request **from** [screenshot]

[image: warning message]

**to** [screenshot]

[image: prompt].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you prompt the user to confirm using `vscode.window.showInformationMessage(...)` to confirm, you can run `vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.reloadWindow")` to reload the window.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer posted by user [ajshort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718526/ajshort) was crucial to figuring out how to call arbitrary editor commands, however, tying it together with user action still wasn't clear to me.

See function bellow for resolving the user action (click).

```
/** Prompts user to reload editor window in order for configuration change to take effect. */
function promptToReloadWindow() {
  const action = 'Reload';

  vscode.window
    .showInformationMessage(
      `Reload window in order for change in extension \`${EXTENSION_ID}\` configuration to take effect.`,
      action
    )
    .then(selectedAction => {
      if (selectedAction === action) {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.reloadWindow');
      }
    });
}
```